# How are globals handled when multiple .c files are involved

Tags: c, parallel-processing

I have have two .c files (main.c and support.c).  Support.c is compiled first and then main.c is compiled and linked with support.o.  I have several non-static global variables in support.c.

How are those global variables from support.c stored?  If main.c is multithreaded and has two threads calling the functions in support.c, are they sharing those globals, or do they each have their own copy?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A global variable is a global variable, and there's always just one, no matter in how many pieces you compile and link your program. If multiple threads access global data concurrently, you need to ensure the proper synchronization yourself.

The only way to get a separate copy of a global or block-static variable is to declare it `_Thread_local`, which was introduced in C11. Thread-local global variables are initialized when the thread is started, and deallocated when the thread is joined.

Comment: @KingsIndian: The header `<threads.h>` defines a macro `thread_local`, but you're right, `_Thread_local` is the more natural keyword.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be confusing the usage of the `static` keyword when it applies to variables that exist top-level in C source (i.e. outside of any functions or methods), vs when you use `static` on variables within a function or keyword.

A variable declared top-level in the source code, outside of any functions, will be global *unless* you declare it as `static`. If it's `static`, it will be local *only* to that file. It controls the *scope* of the variable.

If you declare it `static` inside a function, it controls the *lifetime* of the variable. In this case, the variable will retain itself in memory even after the function call exits, resulting in its value persisting across multiple function calls.

If you declare a global variable (i.e. it's not `static` and is top-level in a source file), there will always only be one instance of it in memory. In other source files, you will have to declare it as `extern` so the linker knows to look for its memory location as defined in the object file for your other file, but there will be only one of it in memory.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to declare the globals as volatile, or the compiler might not realized they can be modified by another thread and make unsafe optimizations.

volatile int g_example;